# Plot png in R using VSCode

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, png

I am unable to export plots as png's in VSCode. I've been working on this for a couple hours and trying every variation I can find but I'm starting to think it might be a VSCode issue.

Here's a sample that ought to work:

```
png("plot.png")
plot(x = mtcars$cyl, y = mtcars$mpg)
dev.off()
```

Another example I found:

```
png(plot <- tempfile(fileext = ".png"))
plot(x = mtcars$cyl, y = mtcars$mpg)
dev.off()
cat(plot, file = "plot.png")
```

Neither of these examples, nor any other, are producing plots. Plus, when I try to manually copy and paste from the plot pane in VSCode, nothing gets copied to the clipboard for export into Paint.

I also tried jumping through the extra hoop discussed here:
[Save base graphics as pseudo-objects](https://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2016/12/08/save-base-graphics-as-pseudo-objects-in-r/)

And read through this github post on implementing plotting in VSCode using R:
[Github issue](https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/issues/51)

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The first code block should work. As for `cat(plot, file="..")` in the second block, you are writing the _string_ (path) of the temp file into the file `"plot.png"`, not the contents. In the first code block, verify the correct directory with `getwd()` (and check that directory if it is not what you expect). The second code block (without `cat(..)`) should be working, have you verified `file.exists(plot)`?

Comment: @r2evans Yeah, I did check the working directory, too, but nothing is dropping into it. I've tried both saving to the work directory and to a specific directory. I suppose it could be an issue that restarting VSCode would solve. I'll give that a try later. Don't want to run all this code again atm.

Comment: I understand. Sorry, I don't use vscode so I can't really help beyond the vanilla R issues. Good luck.

Comment: @hmhensen Can you try running the code in a plain R terminal (started outside of VS Code)? This can help identify whether it's a VS Code issue or an R issue.

Comment: Could you try `dev.off()` in the R-console and check again.  You may repeat this till you get an error. This will make sure that all opened plot devices are closed.